# SpriteKit/Obj C screen width

Tags: sprite-kit

I am going through the flappy bird tutorial for Spritekit.
I am trying to change orientation to vertical, which I have succeeded.
The poster spawns the pipes using:

```
    CGFloat y = arc4random() % (NSInteger)( self.frame.size.height / 3 );
```

to keep the bottom pipe in the bottom third of the screen.

I have modified like so:

```
    CGFloat x = arc4random() % (NSInteger)( self.frame.size.width / 3 );
```

but the pipes are restricted to the right third of the screen. How can it be modified to restrict the left pipe to the left third of the screen.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I completely understand what you're saying. Basically, what the code you have written does is generate a random integer (with the arc4random() method call) and take the remainder (essentially what the % does) of that from dividing by a third of the width of the screen. So the CGFloat value, x, is nothing but random number between 0 and 1/3 the width of the screen in pixels. To modify to restrict the left pipe to the left third of the screen, you could just extend the right pipe to be anywhere from 2/3 the size of the screen to the other end of the screen (assuming this is like a normal flappy bird game where the distance between the pipes is always the same). It would look something like this:

```
CGFloat x = (NSInteger) self.frame.size.width - arc4random() % (NSInteger)( self.frame.size.width / 3 );
```

We're taking the full width of the screen and subtracting a random number between 0 and 1/3 the width of the screen.

Comment: The poster sets a gap between the pipes so the right one is always a fixed distance from the left, which works really good.
I was under the impression that using self.frame.size.width / 3 would restrict the left pipe to the left third only….

Comment: I think I figured it out. Being that the sprite anchor point is the center in SK I need to shorten the pipes...

Comment: self.frame.size.width is getting the width of the screen from the frame. After doing several computations, you set that value to a CGFloat, x, which is really just a number. What makes the pipe stick to the right third of the screen is the way this number is used. You could just restrict the right pipe to be between 2/3 and 1 times the length of the screen but there is no more elegant way of doing it without seeing the rest of the code.